# Can I disable mouse wheel zoom in QGIS?

Tags: qgis

I am having problems with the zoom in QGIS 1.8.0 where a slight move of the scroll wheel on the mouse zooms way way out. It will re-render at each zoom level and with large datasets it takes over the computer for sometimes up to a minute. Is there a way to disable the mouse wheel zoom in QGIS?

Comment: I hope somebody can answer this. It's even worse on laptops with scrolling trackpads.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In the preferences under 'Panning and Zooming' there is a dropdown labeled 'Mouse Wheel Action'

Set this to 'Nothing' and all will be well.

[image]

Comment: You might also want to look at the options on the identify function as changing them from the default 'selected' is more like Arcmap

Comment: Also found that setting Mouse Wheel Action as 'Zoom to mouse cursor' and setting Zoom factor to 1.1 is a reasonable work-a-round. Then a light tap on the magic mouse if zooming in too fast will stop the zoom in its tracks.

Comment: Any ideas how to do this in QGIS3? The option seems to have been removed.